# Separate a module into smaller parts

Tags: javascript

The file is quite long, 1000 LOC so I want to separate it into smaller files.

https://github.com/anvoz/world-js/blob/v1.0/js/world.core.js

Here is a brief version of the code:

```
(function(window, undefined) {
    var WorldJS = window.WorldJS = function() {
        // WorldJS Constructor
        this.nextSeedId = 1;
        this.Statistic = { population: 0 };
        this.Knowledge = {
            completed: [],
            gain: function(world) { /* ... */ }
        };
    }
    WorldJS.prototype.someMethods = function() {};

    var Seed = WorldJS.prototype.Seed = function() {
        // Seed Constructor
    };
    Seed.prototype.someMethods = function() {};
})(window);

// Create a world
var world = new WorldJS();
// Create a seed
var seed = new world.Seed();
```

Seems like I was right with the `Seed` class. So I can put `Seed` in a new file. Like this:

```
(function(window, undefined) {
    var WorldJS = window.WorldJS;
    var Seed = WorldJS.prototype.Seed = function() {
        // Seed Constructor
    };
    Seed.prototype.someMethods = function() {};
})(window);
```

How can I put the `Knowledge` property to a new file? Is it a good practice if I change `Knowledge` to a class just like the `Seed` class and use a new lowercase property to hold data like this:

```
world.knowledge = new world.Knowledge();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the advantage of adding `Seed` and `Knowledge` into the prototype of `World` (unless you've got more code to tell me otherwise). If you don't need anything from the instance at all, then you don't need them in the instance. You can put them like `static` members instead.

With that, you can do what jQuery did. jQuery's `jQuery` and `$` point to a constructor function that builds jQuery objects. That's why you can do `jQuery()` and `$()`.

But in JS, functions *are objects* and like any other object, you can add properties. It's the same reason why you can also do `jQuery.each` or `$.each`. Basically they made their constructor their namespace as well.

So you can do the following to `World`:

```
(function(window){

  var World = window.World = function(){/*World constructor code*/};

  World.prototype.someFn = function(){/*...*/};

}(window));
```

And like how non-instance jQuery plugins extend (and yes, you can place this in another file. Just make sure the `World` library is loaded first):

```
(function(World){

  //This part would be synonymous to $.somePlugin = function(){...}
  var Seed = World.Seed = function(){/*Seed constructor code*/};

  Seed.prototype.someFn = function(){/*...*/};

}(World));
```

To use them:

```
var myWorld = new World();        //Using World as a constructor
var mangoSeed = new World.Seed(); //Using World to access the Seed constructor
```

Comment: I use prototype for `Seed` because some properties of Seed may different in 2 `WorldJS` instances. However, I completely forgot about the properties of function as you mentioned so your answer is very helpful and may make my code clearer. I will review my code again to see if I can change as you suggest. How about the `Knowledge` property of `WorldJS`?